# how to focus a specific textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, focus

I'm making a desktop application in vb.net. When I click the back button (placed by me) on any form it hides current form and shows previous form but when i go again to the form from which i had hit back button then the focus cue still remains on the back button but I want the focus to be on the first textbox on that form or any specific button on which I want.....How can i achieve this...

I have already used some code to shift focus from one textbox to another when i press enter key...but it doesn't work in the above mentioned case....I'm using vb.net in visual studio 2005...

This is the code i'm using for shifting focus among textboxes

```
Private Sub party_code_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles party_code.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then
        party_name.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me on this????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a handler for either the form's Activated event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    party_name.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: @user944591: Excellent! I have updated the answer appropriately.